# How to search through and update some text only, leaving out text inside some element name

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have this HTML fragment:

```
<p>Yes.  No.  Both. Maybe a <a href="/plane">plane</a>?</p><h2 id="2-is-it-a-plane">2. Is it a plane?</h2><p>Yes.  No.  Both.</p><h2 id="3-what-is-superman-anyway">3. What is Superman, anyway?</h2><p>Is it a bird?  Is it a plane?  No, it’s Superman.</p>
```

I need to replace the word `plane` with

```
<a href="/some/url">plane</a>
```

but only when it's outside of an `<a></a>` anchor tag, and outside a heading, `<h1-h6></h>` tag.

This is what I've tried:

```
require 'Nokogiri'
h = '<p>Yes.  No.  Both. Maybe a <a href="/plane">plane</a>?</p><h2 id="2-is-it-a-plane">2. Is it a plane?</h2><p>Yes.  No.  Both.</p><h2 id="3-what-is-superman-anyway">3. What is Superman, anyway?</h2><p>Is it a bird?  Is it a plane?  No, it’s Superman.</p>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment(h).parse

# Try 1: This outputs all content, but I need to avoid <a>/<h#>
doc.content 

# Try 2: The below line removes headings permanently - I need them to remain 
# doc.search(".//h2").remove

# Try 3: This just comes out empty - why?
# doc.xpath('text()')    
# doc.xpath('//text()')

# then,
# code to replace `plane` is here ...
# this part is not needed
# then,
doc.to_html
```

I tried various other variations of `xpath` to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around, it appears you needed to use the XPath selector `p/text()`. Things then got more complicated because you're trying to replace normal text with a link element.

When I just tried using `gsub`, Nokogiri was escaping the new link, so I needed to split the text element into multiple sibling elements where I could replace some of the siblings with link elements instead of text nodes.

```
doc.xpath('p/text()').grep(/plane/) do |node|
  node_content, *remaining_texts = node.content.split(/(plane)/)

  node.content = node_content
  remaining_texts.each do |text|
    if text == 'plane' 
      node = node.add_next_sibling('<a href="/some/url">plane</a>').last
    else
      node = node.add_next_sibling(text).last
    end
  end
end

puts doc
# <p>Yes.  No.  Both. Maybe a <a href="/plane">plane</a>?</p>
# <h2 id="2-is-it-a-plane">2. Is it a plane?</h2>
# <p>Yes.  No.  Both.</p>
# <h2 id="3-what-is-superman-anyway">3. What is Superman, anyway?</h2>
# <p>Is it a bird?  Is it a <a href="/some/url">plane</a>?  No, it’s Superman.</p>
```

A more general purpose XPath selector for all elements, except headings and links, might be:

```
*[not(name()='a')][not(name()='h1')][not(name()='h2')][not(name()='h3')][not(name()='h4')][not(name()='h5')][not(name()='h6')]/text()
```

You may need to tweak this some as I'm not an XML or Nokogiri expert, but it appears to me to be working for the provided example, at least, so it should get you going.